# My for statement keeps repeating even though I set a limit?

Tags: c++, macos

My for statement keeps repeating even though I set a limit? (Sorry I'm completely new at this) I'm not sure how to keep it from repeating forever. It also goes off even when the condition I set is not met, is this supposed to happen?

```
// Garbage Collection
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  double reg, glass, met;
  double total;
  double reg_ratio, glass_ratio, met_ratio;

  cin >> reg;
  cin >> glass;
  cin >> met;

  total = met + glass + reg;

  cout << "The total number of bags is " << total << endl;

  met_ratio = met / total;
  reg_ratio = reg / total;
  glass_ratio = glass / total;

  cout << "The metal ratio is " << met_ratio << endl;
  cout << "The glass ratio is " << glass_ratio << endl;
  cout << "The regular ratio is " << reg_ratio << endl;

  if (met==reg==glass) {
    cout << "All garbage amounts are the same." << endl;
  }
  else if (reg > glass && met) {
    cout << "Regular is the largest." << endl;
  }
  else if (glass > met && reg) {
    cout << "Glass is the largest." << endl;
  }
  else if (met> glass && reg) {
    cout << "Metal is the largest." << endl;
  }

  for (reg >= 50; reg+reg;) {
    cout << "I can't take anymore." << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't set a limit, look up the syntax of a `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

That's not how a `for` works. It's:

```
for (initial statement; condition; iteration operation)
```

The `initial statement` is executed once, on first entry in the loop, the loop is executed for as long as `condition` is true, and the operation executes on every iteration.

In your case, the initial statement is `reg >= 50`, which does nothing, the condition is `reg+reg` which will only be false if `reg+reg` somehow evaluated to `false`, and there's no operation.

`reg+reg` doesn't modify `reg` mind you. The operation you're looking for is probably `reg += reg`.

Comment: Thank you! Simple mistake, glad you could help me out.

Comment: The condition `reg+reg` will evaluate to `false` if `reg` is `0.0` ;)

Answer (score 3):

`for(initialization; condition; increment-code)` is how a for-loop works (note: all three parts are optional). If `condition` is `true`, it continues the loop. You mixed this up and wrote it as `for(condition; increment-code; *empty*)`. Note that your condition seems inversed. Also, your incrementing part doesn't actually update `reg`, you add it to itself and throw the result away.

The correct code is

```
for(; reg <= 50; reg += reg)
```

Also note that your `if` statements seem *very* bogus.

```
if (reg> glass && met)
```

First, please put a space around binary operations. Next, this will only test ift `reg` is bigger than `glass` and if `met` is a non-zero value. To test if `reg` is both bigger than `glass` and bigger than `met`, you have to do that explicitly twice:

```
if(reg > glass && reg > met)
```

May I recommend [a good book](http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks)?

Comment: Ahh thank you, makes sense now, and sure any recommendations would be great!

Comment: @Mike: I hope you noticed that the "a good book" part is a link to a recommended book list maintained by professional C++ programmers. :)

Answer (score 0):

What reported from the other users is correct: The `for` statement you wrote would never end, and would not change any variable. [Xeo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500104/xeo) gave you the correct way to write the `for` statement.

What I would add is that the `for`-loop should contain instructions that need to be executed when the condition is true. In your case, it seems the instruction you are executing is for when the condition is not anymore true. if you just want to write a message when the variable is higher than a value, you should use a `if` statement.

```
if (reg >= 50) {
  cout << "I can't take more." << endl;
}
```